# What is the name of this type of pinned barrel connector?

Tags: power-supply, identification, connector, hard-drive

This is for an old Seagate/Barracuda disk drive. It is most likely run from a 12 V, 3 A power supply. I am looking for a replacement, but I don't know what connector type to search for.

[image: female power connection]

Comment: Thomas Matthew - Hi, Re: "most likely run from a 12v 3amp power supply" Just FYI, the times I have most often seen that connector type (which has kindly already been identified for you) is when the PSU (wall wart) was providing both 12 V *and* 5 V to the external HDD case, hence the need to have 4 pins (well, at least 3 pins since they share a ground). Please check whether that applies to your external drive (some external drive cases have an onboard buck converter to generate the required 5V, so only 12V is need from the external PSU; others need both voltages supplied from the PSU).

Comment: @Thomas Matthew - To follow up from what Sam Gibson said, searching for ``9W6044-540`` found [AC ADAPTER FOR SEAGATE ST3160026ARK 9W6044-570 9W6044-540 HDD POWER PAYLESS](https://www.findpowercord.com/ac-adapter-for-seagate-st3160026ark-9w6044-570-9w6044-540-hdd-power-payless/) which contains ``Output: 12V and 5V 1.5~2A Up to 34Watts``. I.e. two supply voltages. Albeit that is from a 3rd party site and can't find any authoritative information on the Seagate site.

Comment: If it's the same enclosure, the YouTube video [How to open a Seagate Pushbutton Backup enclosure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iw_bFrAY58c) may be helpful. Then you can examine the board in the enclosure to see if it has a 5 V regulator on it or if it needs the external power supply to give the drive 5 V. If my experience of old Seagate drives is anything to go by, the drive will be dead anyway. Do you have an old computer with an IDE disk interface that you could try it with before looking for an external mains adapter?

Answer (score 6):

It's a 4-pin mini-DIN connector. [Here](https://www.l-com.com/images/downloadables/2D/BAC-MD4M_2D.pdf) is a mating connector which you can double check for dimensions.

Comment: Can use an S-video cable to connect

Comment: @DDuck Your question is basically like asking if you can use a USB device that has a circular connector instead of rectangular. As long as the DIN connector is S-Video compliant, then yes. S-Video is not a connector type; it's a standard for video data and/or transmission.

Comment: Maybe. S-video cables are 75Ω controlled impedance (which means they are optimized for something other than carrying power) and may be too high resistance for this purpose. Note @Sam's comment that there are probably 5V/12V dual supplies required or they would have used a smaller/cheaper connector. It does appear to be DC from the markings.